# Pointwise multiplication and right matrix division

Tags: r, matlab

I'm currently trying to recreate this Matlab function in R:

```
function X = uniform_sphere_points(n,d)

% X = uniform_sphere_points(n,d)
%
%function generates n points unformly within the unit sphere in d dimensions


z= randn(n,d);

r1 = sqrt(sum(z.^2,2));

X=z./repmat(r1,1,d);
r=rand(n,1).^(1/d);

X = X.*repmat(r,1,d);
```

Regarding the the right matrix division I installed the [pracma](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pracma/pracma.pdf) package. My R code right now is:

```
uniform_sphere_points <- function(n,d){
  # function generates n points uniformly within the unit sphere in d dimensions

  z = rnorm(n, d)

  r1 = sqrt(sum(z^2,2))

  X = mrdivide(z, repmat(r1,1,d))

  r = rnorm(1)^(1/d)

  X = X * matrix(r,1,d)

  return(X)
}
```

But it is not really working since I always end with a non-conformable arrays error in R.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This operation for sampling `n` random points from the `d`-dimensional unit sphere could be stated in words as:

1. Construct a `n` x `d` matrix with entries drawn from the standard normal distribution
2. Normalize each row so it has (2-norm) magnitude 1
3. For each row, compute a random value by taking a draw from the uniform distribution (between 0 and 1) and raise that value to the `1/d` power. Multiply all elements in the row by that value.

The following R code does these operations:

```
unif.samp <- function(n, d) {
  z <- matrix(rnorm(n*d), nrow=n, ncol=d)
  z * (runif(n)^(1/d) / sqrt(rowSums(z^2)))
}
```

Note that in the second line of code I have taken advantage of the fact that multiplying a `n` x `d` matrix in R by a vector of length `n` will multiply each row by the corresponding value in that vector. This saves us the work of using `repmat` to construct matrices of exactly the same size as our original matrix for these sorts of row-specific operations.